# I can't call php functions outside method scope?

Tags: php, class, methods

Me and my coworker entered in a argument in which she said that we could'nt call any functions outside a method scope in a controller, and I think its possible.

Today my code is in the following way:

index.php:

```
<?php

require_once("baseController.php");

?>


<h1>
  HERE I PROVE SOMETHING
</h1>

<?php

echo '<pre>', print_r(BaseController::aluno, 1), '<pre>';

?>
```

baseController.php

```
<?php

require_once('Aluno.php');


class BaseController{

  public static $aluno = new Aluno();

}
```

Aluno.php

```
<?php

class Aluno{

  public $nome;
  public $idade;


}
```

I don't really know what am I doing wrong, am I not allowed to do this? Always when I try to run the code it generates a error 500 in the console. What is happening here?

Comment: Wrong syntax at `public static $aluno = new Aluno();` you can not create an instance at this point. When developing always use `error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: `public static $aluno = new Aluno();`. Expressions are now allowed as field default values. You'll have to use a setter or a `__construct`.

Comment: Well, did you test it? Also, calling php with <? is bad, use <?php instead.

Comment: but how would I do something like this, to in the index.php function have acesses to a static variable that contains Aluno?

Comment: Mate, read up on theory first. It's possible, yes, and quite simple to do too.

Comment: _“Always when I try to run the code it generates a error 500 in the console”_ – well then you _start_ by checking the error log (or configuring PHP to display errors directly in the script output) to find out what PHP has to tell you about the error.

Comment: Mate, could you point me to the theory, its quite hard to find.